# Bootstrap 4: Beautify navigation bar dropdown on mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4

**Problem**

Currently, the navigation dropdown on my mobile does not look "modern". However, when I use chrome to enter the developer mode (f12) and change to the mobile view, it shows a modern-looking dropdown.

**Code**

Im using Bootstrap 4.3.1

```
<?php if (isset($admin) && $admin) { ?>
                    <!-- Dropdown -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Admin
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#da3744" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Administrator/userManagement.php">User Management</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                <?php } ?>
```

**Question**

Is there a fix to make the dropdown look on my mobile to be the same as chrome?

**Powered by chrome**

[image: trap]

**Powered by iPhone XS Max ios 13.3 safari**

[image]

Comment: There are no colleagues around who use the IPhone XS Max, but I have tested the IPhone XR and XS, and I didn't find the problem you mentioned.Can you provide your code?

Comment: @多一点点爱 I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `type="button"`

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
      data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Admin
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color:#da3744" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./Administrator/userManagement.php">
          User Management
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
          Another action
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider">
        </div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
          Something else here
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i kinda mistyped role as type